# Height of screen in portrait mode only?

Tags: android

How can I get the height of the device for portrait mode? I have to create a bitmap (which is zoomable) and I just want to get a rough idea what the tallest height should be.

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

does the above return the height, in portrait mode only?

I'm not binding my UI to this absolute value, it's just a rough fit,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int potraitHeight = Math.max(d.getWidth(),d.getHeight());
```

Comment: @steelbytes: :thumbup:
@user: You might also want to check this out:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/435390/Android/Mobile/get-screen-size-at-run

Comment: I strongly discourage you from getting the raw display size; this does not give you an accurate value for the space you will actually have.

It is far better to use the normal view hierarchy facilities to see what size a view is given during layout, such as by overriding onSizeChanged().

Comment: agreed about screen physical vs avaialble ... I just answered the literal Q.